# Excel gives a False instead of True for simple formula

Tags: excel

I just stumbled on an Excel 2013 problem I've never encountered.

Briefly, I have a column (= V for my particular sheet) that returns a 0 or 1 based on two numbers matching exactly (i.e., no rounding errors). This is simple error checking for my work.

In cell F31, I have = 0.1 (manually entered). In cells M31, L31, and J31, I have 4.5, 0.0, and 4.4,  respectively. A formula in cell Q31 is
Q31 = M31 - L31 - J31. This is 4.5 - 0.0 - 4.4 = 0.1. None of these numbers come from other formulae. There should be no rounding errors.

Now, in column V31, I have If(Q31=F31,0,1). No doubt that 0.1 [F31] = 0.1 [Q31], but the return value in V is 1. This makes no sense!

If I enter other values so that Q31 does not = 0.1 but F31 = Q31, the return value is 0 (or Q31 = F31) as it should be. For example, I can change F31 to 0.2 and L31 to 4.3 so that 0.2 = 0.2 based on 4.5 - 0.0 - 4.3. This works fine.

What's up with the 0.1?

Many thanks!
Eric

Comment: Expand the decimals in Q31 you will get `0.099999999999999600` it is a floating point error.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are *"almost never"* equal. It's due to floating point arithmetic and precision.

Not all decimal numbers have an exact floating-point representation. A value you enter by hand, must be replaced by Excel by the *closest* floating-point representation. Also, a value resulting from calculation is replaced by the *floating-point unit* of the processor by its closest value.

When comparing floating point numbers, use some "epsilon" tolerance. Use something like this for your `V31` formula:

```
=IF(ABS(Q31-F31) < 1e-10, 0, 1)
```

This compares the two numbers up to the 10th decimal digit.

For flexibility, you can define a "Name" for your tolerance constant, "TOL" in the name manager, so that you can change it in one place without editing your formulas.

```
=IF(ABS(Q31-F31) < TOL, 0, 1)
```

The choice of the tolerance depends on your application.`1e-10` is a good choice in many cases.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you so much for this spot-on answer. I also learned that equality checks in MATLAB face the same complication (although variable type can be defined... I think). It must have been dumb luck that I never had problems in past. Your kind answer will save me a lot of grief in the future. As an experiment, I tried formatting cells as currency, thinking two monetary decimal places would be more "fixed" (i.e. any digits far to right of decimal point are truncated). This didn't help, so I guess a tolerance is needed for basic finance, too. Thanks again! Best, Eric